# Auto-login in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, login

Does anyone know a (verified) method to cause a specific user to auto-login after a system reboot, that works on Server 2008?

I've tried tweaking some registry values (I don't have the link right now) and we've also tried a couple of programs (one free program didn't work, another one costs money).

**Edit**
Since several people have asked for my reasons - I need to run Selenium web tests on a TeamCity build agent, and they don't work well when the build runs as a windows service. Running them in a user session solves the problem.

Comment: What is the reason for wanting this? Perhaps it can be resolved by doing whatever needs doing as a service or a scheduled task?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For a Windows 2008 domain member, add **AutoAdminLogon** as a string value (REG_SZ)  with a value of **1** to the key

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

Next, run the User Accounts control panel by typing **control userpasswords2** in the Run command.

On the Users tab, uncheck the box *"Users must enter a username..."* and then add the username and password to autologon with.

Comment: It is not until you give up on the last step (where do I type in the user name and password, oh I give up and press ok), that you are prompted for the user name and password.

Comment: Must check and uncheck users must enter a user name and password ..., then press ok.

Comment: How can this be used to login multiple users?

Answer (score 8):

You may try [autologon](http://live.sysinternals.com/) form sysinternals. It permits you to make windows logon automaticaly under a specified account with the credentials encrypted.

Answer (score 3):

Helpful Tip on Windows autologin:  Any Legal Notice that pops up before Windows prompts for user name and password will stop autologin.  There may be a way to click passed the prompt automatically, but it was easier to just delete the annoying keys in the registry:

Open regedit, delete the string values in the two keys:
* LegalNoticeCaption
** LegalNoticeText
in HKLM\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon

source for the registry edits:  http://www.annoyances.org/exec/forum/winxp/t1107277811

In Server 2008 these same keys are also found in: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policy\System

Be sure to check in both locations to be certain the values have been deleted.

The legal notice issue was causing our autologin to hang.  Since this was on a remote 2008 Server in the Verizon cloud it was impossible to watch the autologin after a reboot.

The sysinternals autologin tool works very well to get autologin to work.  It is already referenced earlier in this post.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/runasservice/. It's a tool to run an existing application as a service. This service should use your desired user account. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You say you need the program to run in a specific user session.  Can't you just schedule a task for that program and use that user's credentials?  You'll get the whole user settings: my documents, settings, etc, just as if the user was present.

Comment: I don't want to schedule it, I want to raise the entire build agent process (that should run always) when the machine starts.

Comment: Schedule task for Windows 2003 allows you to schedule a task to run at system startup.  I'm sure 2008 has that choice as well.

Comment: Still, I want a proper session, the user credentials are not enough. When I tried running it as a service (under the same user credentials), it didn't work.

Comment: Running as a service is not the same as running as a scheduled task.  I really believe that an exe running under a scheduled task is a proper session.  The only thing I'm not sure about is if the process insisted on displaying stuff on a real CRT.  Since I've done this with vanilla apps, their display stuff goes into the bit bucket.  Give it a shot; it's such a cleaner solution than some of the other suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure you need to do that? It's always a security risk to have a user (or administrator) logged in locally to a server. If you need to start a program or something that is not available as service, have a look at Group Policy (Active Directory) or the Local Security Policy (if not in a domain). You can define scripts that will be run after boot (or before shutdown, after login/logout, etc) without user interaction.

Comment: I need a program to run in a specific user session. I don't really care about security, it's in the company intranet.

Comment: I am running in virtual-box.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315231) should work-or at least it always has for me. I know it says for XP but it should apply: