# How can I launch RemoteApp on Windows Server from server itself at startup

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop-services, remoteapp

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 with RDS and custom desktop (GUI) application installed on the server. The app is started as RemoteApp on server by user from his desktop computer (or, sometimes, he can work from notebook over VPN).

Some details about environment:

- the server automatically shuts down every evening and automatically power-on every morning (this is a requirement)
- desktop application do some precalculations/precaching on startup and it can take lot of time
- mentioned application have some memory leaks, so I can't use hibernate instead of shutdown

When user launching this app from his computer, he can't start work with it until this app finishes pre-initialization.

Is there any way to start RemoteApp session at the server startup (without actual user logon), so that the user could connect to this session from his computer later? I don't want to involve the user's computer to make it work.

I have tried to do it by Windows startup script, but have no luck - starting RDP session requires actual user session.

Comment: This has been asked before but I can't find the link at the moment...

Comment: I'm sorry, but why would you turn a server off over night?

Comment: This is fire safety requirement in an office. There was an incident 2 years ago, "_once bitten, twice shy_"

Comment: Could you hibernate the server instead of shutting it down? The session would still be alive the next day, then.

Comment: mentioned application have some memory leaks, so I can't use hibernate instead of shutdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server is not accessible physically by everybody, you could try to configure [autologin on the console](https://serverfault.com/questions/73592/auto-login-in-windows-server-2008) and just drop the `.rdp` file(s) (with saved credentials if needed) into the startup.

After for example 5 minutes you can log off the console session again. If you login as dedicated user you will not startup all sessions if you log in to work as administrator

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something as simple as couple of regedits or startup folder?

```
HKLM/SOFTWARE/MICROSOFT/WINDOWS/CURRENT VERSION/RUN
```

Comment: This registry key provides same functions as Windows startup script do. But, as I have said - starting RDP session requires actual user session.

Comment: unless you automate mstsc.exe with .rdp files like mentioned above.